# Can Sudoku be solved using matroid theory?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Advanced sudoku-solving seems rather streamlined:

- for each square write down the acceptable values
- Using a [standard set of techniques](http://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/sudoku/techniques) - many of which I did not know by name - deduce the values of certain squares or rule out possibilities.

There seem to be a few more techniques with interesting names:

### x-wing

[image]

### swordfish

[image]

### xy-wing

[image]

### unique rectangle

[image]

#### Can matroid theory offer a general framework for these techniques?

What happens when you try to solve the "generalized" sudoku's you see in magazines?  I try to imagine the numbers 1..9 like basis vectors in some crazy vector-space-like object and we need to check these "independence" conditions as we look from various angles.  Can this be formalized?

[image]    [(source)](http://www.sachsentext.de/gif/starsudoku1.gif)

Comment: Isn't there already a general framework for Sudoku-like problems?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover

Comment: Matroids can help with Sudoku verification.  See  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129600/is-there-a-sudoku-matroid and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129143/verifying-the-correctness-of-a-sudoku-solution

Comment: It will be worth my time to study Knuth's "dancing links" algorithm!

Comment: A very closely related MO question (a duplicate perhaps?):
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129600/is-there-a-sudoku-matroid