# Minimal-information description of sudoku solution (Latin square)

Tags: co.combinatorics, latin-square, sudoku

Sudoku puzzles consist of a $9 \times 9$ grid of cells in which some cells contain integers from the set $\{ 1, \ldots, 9 \}$ and the task is to fill in the remaining cells such that the numbers $1$ through $9$ appear in each row, in each column, and in each of the nine $3 \times 3$ boxes, as shown in this puzzle and its solution:

[image: Minimal sudoku puzzle and solution]

The solutions are also called *Latin squares*, and one estimate of the number of distinct $9 \times 9$ such Latin squares is $N = 6,670,903,752,021,072,936,960$.

I am interested in finding the minimum-information description of such a solution by describing the minimal *puzzle* that leads to that unique solution.  Of course such a solution has a very large number of constraints, which reduces the information needed to describe its source puzzle.  In information theoretic terms, one need merely describe (or transmit) the minimal puzzle; the receiver can then solve the puzzle to fill in the full Latin square.

In a tour de force simulation taking the equivalent of $7.3M$ hours on a supercomputer, [Gary McGraw, Bastian Tugemann and Giles Civario](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0749.pdf) solved a long-outstanding problem:  finding that the minimal number of puzzle cells needed to be filled to ensure a unique sudoku solution was 17 (as exemplified in the figure above).  No $16$-clue puzzles exist.

A lower-bound on the information needed to describe such a puzzle would assume that the grid locations for the $17$ clues are fixed (and hence contribute zero bits to the description), and that all one need do is fill in the $17$ puzzle cell values.  One might assume the maximum entropy set such as ${\cal S} = \{ 1,1,2,2,3,3,\ldots,8,8,9 \}$, i.e., one instance of a single digit, and two copies of each remaining digit.  Thus it takes $\log_2 9 = 3.16993$ bits to describe which is the "lone" or "singleton" digit.  Then the creation of the puzzle corresponds to placing the 17 digits of ${\cal S}$ in the $17$ (assumed fixed) cells, thus requiring $\log_2 \left({17! \over (2!)^8} \right) = 40.3376$ bits, so the total number of bits is:  $3.16993 + 40.3376 = 43.5075$ bits.  (Note that this is much lower than the naive estimate of $\log_2 N = 72.4984$ bits.)

I suspect this estimate is a loose lower bound because (perhaps) not all puzzles can be described by $17$ cell values, that even if one could use just $17$ such values the cell *locations* might need to differ (and hence require information to describe these locations), and other factors.  Moreover, as @ZachTeitler pointed out, many of the assignments of digits to cells will lead to unsolvable puzzles (because, for example, there will be two equal digits in the same row, or column, or $3 \times 3$ box).

I don't expect someone to solve this problem fully on this site--it simply requires too much analysis and likely massive computer simulations.  What I would appreciate are comments/criticisms on the casting of this problem and its assumptions, and a clear methodological approach toward solving it rigorously.

Comment: You might enjoy reading this old question and its answers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129143

Comment: Suppose I give you k bits of information to represent a Sudoku solution.  If k is less than log_2 N, how would I use k bits or fewer to distinguish each of the other N-1 solutions?  Are you asking about equivalence classes of solutions instead?  Gerhard "Finds The Question Itself Puzzling" Paseman, 2018.10.24.

Comment: 1. Can you please explain where $\binom{17}{9}/(2!)^8$ comes from? The number of ways to put $1,1,2,2,\dotsc,8,8,9$ into $17$ squares is $17!/(2!)^8$. If you allow a choice of which digit is the "odd" one ($9$) then you get $9 \cdot 17!/(2!)^8$. Have I misunderstood what you are counting? 2. Presumably the large majority of placements into those $17$ squares fail to uniquely determine a puzzle solution. Either they admit more than one solution (failure of uniqueness) or they admit no solutions — e.g., if the $17$ clue squares have a duplicated digit in a row, column, or region. ...

Comment: ... counting these seems like a challenge, to put it mildly. It will certainly depend on *which* $17$ squares are chosen for the clue locations. E.g., if the $17$ squares are the first row and first column, then very, very few clue fillings will uniquely determine puzzle solutions!

Comment: @ZachTeitler:  My guess/ansatz was that a unique selection of 17 cell locations *might* uniquely determine all sudoku puzzles, but that set would be arranged like the set in my example, certainly *not* a row and a column.  (Frankly, that would be one of the *least* constraining arrangements.

Comment: No single selection of $17$ locations will come close to determining all puzzles. Your bit count shows this. On top of that, a lot of bits are "wasted" on unsolvable clues (e.g., two $1$s in the same row). Here's a question. Is there some set of, say, $23$ squares that *does* uniquely determine all puzzles? $23$ is the least integer greater than $\log_9(N)$, so there are $>N$ ways to fill clues into a set of $23$ squares. My guess is no, you would need more than $23$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler:  Good point:  Some of the assignments of digits to $17$ cells will lead to unsolvable puzzles.  Indeed, perhaps the better question is how few ($23$?) cells suffice such that some subset can be chosen (with digit assignments) such that the expected information content (in bits) is minimal.  (I'll revise the question.)  Thanks.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman:  What is becoming clear is that the assumption that a fixed $17$ cells together with the minimum-information assignment of digits to those cells cannot lead to a tight bound on the number of bits needed to describe a latin square.  ZachTeitler's improvement of the question is:  How few cells need be specified ahead of time ($k = 23?$) such that an assignment of digits leads to a unique solution *such that* the total information (in bits) of the cell sub-selection and digit assignments can describe *all* Latin squares.  Presumably the total information will be $\log_2 N$.

Comment: Not much more. There are some universal patterns (33 squares, I think) which guarantee a Sudoku solution if it exists.  I think it is easy to find these patterns, and possibly work ones way down.  Gerhard "Unpublished And Half Remembered Work" Paseman, 2018.10.24.