# How should you respond to a student who asks whether a very nice physical example constitutes a proof?

Tags: mathematics-education, teaching, gm.general-mathematics

"Is this really a proof?" is the exact question e-mailed to me today from an undergraduate mathematics student whom I know as a highly competent student. The one sentence question was accompanied with the following demo:

[image]

I am looking for a down-to-earth, non-authoritative answer who one may give to such a student. What would be your answer if you were faced with such a question?

**Update after closure**. Reading the comments you may realized that most of them answer the original title of the post: "Is this really a proof?" Of course, the answer to such a question is as clear as the daylight for MO users. And, such a question should be closed asap. But, the actual question was (is) in the body of the post, and it was (is) what your **constructive** answer would be **to such a student** if you were faced with such a question. Now, with the change of the title, the actual question is much more clearer, and I hope, worthy of MO attention.

Comment: No. It's not an actual proof. It's an excellent example, though.

Comment: I'm with Asaf.  A very pretty device.  But you know the angles, lengths and volumes are not exact.  And there are a lot of other shapes of right triangle.  A proof has to cover all that.

Comment: I want one of those.

Comment: I think the first question would be: A proof of what? Clearly not a proof of pythagoras, perhaps a proof that the volume of the 2 small containers is equal to the volume of the 3rd. Even then I'm not sure, although that's how I'd test it.

Comment: No proof. A magician could use containers with different depths to 'prove' fake theorems.

Comment: I modified the title to make it closer to the question asked.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd It is indeed a very constructive modification. Thanks. Consequently I need to modify my description. I'll do it now.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your student is even asking.  To me, it sounds like the student has seen this presented online as a proof and is skeptical, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: There are two things in your image that are different from what is commonly accepted as a mathematical proof.  First, it involves a physical (concrete) system, instead of an idealized (abstract) one.  Thus, it cannot show an equality, only an approximation.  That is, it is not precise.  Second, it involves a specific instance of the problem, not a generalization.  It shows that the statement is true for that triangle, but not necessarily for all triangles.

Comment: @HenryCohn Indeed, as I mentioned before, he is a highly competent mathematics student. I asked him why he asked such a question. Here is the story. He was teaching a high school math course when his students came up with the question. His answer was "as far as I know, in mathematics a proof is constructed based on axioms". I feel, his answer works for him (us) individually, but it is not a constructive answer for his (our) students as such. That is why I asked the question.

Comment: It is a pity that MO does not seem to be a good place to ask mathematics education-related questions.  While there are other mathematics education-related question-and-answer websites, the ones I know of do not have an active and representative community of users.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I am sure MO users are faced with such down-to-earth situations in their everyday teaching life. I am happy that there are several occasions that MO has accepted that fact in the past. Let's hope for the future.

Comment: Well, it's a fun device, but aside from the obvious objections given before, it also doesn't give any insight into why the theorem is true. Isn't that really what a proof is good for?

Comment: I'd maintain that (very?) arguably this is a (not that great) demonstration that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ for one certain particular triangle. It shares some relation to a drawing on graph paper. It is a motivation for a formal proof. Some science museums have  whispering galleries demonstrating a reflective property of ellipses.

Comment: You can also build physical models of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle and they do not prove anything :-) (One can use larger and larger Fibonacci triangles to do this, and the error can be made as small as most sensible measuring instruments)

Comment: Dear Amir, Here is my reaction, which might also be what I would say to the student: first of all, we could just measure the sides of a right-angled triangle, square them and compare the sum of two to the third; if we did so carefully, we would get good agreement.  The demonstration with water is basically just a fancier way of doing the same thing.  Your student probably understands that checking one example is not the same as proving a general theorem, and could also probably understand that even in one example, measurements and so on are imprecise, so this is really only an approximate ...

Comment: ... verification even in that case.  *But*, so as not to be purely negative, one can also remark that the fact that real-world measurements give such good accordance with the theorems of Euclidean geometry shows that the geometry of the world (at least on a small scale near the surface of the earth) is very close to Euclidean, something that is not automatic (and not *exactly* true). [Looking at the answers below, I guess my comment is similar in spirit to Paul Garrett's answer.]    Regards,

Comment: I was just asked (as a reviewer) whether this should be reopened. My answer is 'no'. But if I were teaching such a high school course, then (to repeat what has already been said) "seeing is not always believing"; otherwise we should believe magicians are really capable of producing magic. On the other hand, "a proof is any completely convincing argument" (Errett Bishop), and has nothing to hide. A good proof will moreover be illuminating; in the present case, if you assume the parallel postulate and the sum of three angles being 180 degrees, the Pythagorean theorem is a beautiful consequence.

Comment: Just came across this (closed) question. Perhaps you would find this MO post to be of interest: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104714/building-a-physical-model-to-solve-sudoku

Answer (score 10):

*Approximate* equality in one or more examples is all that can be demonstrated by physical measurements and pictures. This certainly is a useful first step in proof of "exact" (ideal) equality, or in suggesting that there might be an underlying causal mechanism. But there are many geometric dissection problems/puzzles (which I cannot quickly locate, unfortunately) which seem, pictorially, to decompose a figure into pieces whose total area does not add up to the true total. Of course, the "catch" is a tiny imprecision in drawing.

Nevertheless, if a physical demonstration is not deliberately "rigged" to give a deceitful result, an accidental measured-equality is on the whole very convincing, in the same way that so-called Monte-Carlo testing is fairly convincing.

Methodologically, too, I suppose one routinely checks the *plausibility* of an assertion before allocating much effort to proving it, and physical demonstrations can be quick and effective. (Maybe construction of such an elaborate model as in the demo above wouldn't be usual!)

For that matter, the Euclidean picture-drawing rules-of-proof are themselves a fairly stylized game, as corroborated by Hilbert-et-al's eventual observation that there were some implicit assumptions. Not that the two-thousand-year-old conclusions were wrong, but only that some visual/physical assumptions were being used, in addition to a supposed axiomatic set-up.

Pictures and physical demos certainly capture a diffident audience's attention better than narrative.

Comment: @DanFox, yes, I realize that the demo above was not a random-measurement situation, which is what I meant to contrast to. Thus, that demo, obviously contrived with some trouble, at best demonstrates plausibility. I guess I was unclear...

Comment: One such dissection problem is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/348298/18398

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche... Excellent! :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Clearly it is not a proof. In the same way we could "demonstrate" the squaring of the circle (and it has been done more or less that way already by many amateurs). However, isn't it nice to "see" Pythagoras that way ?