# Finding closest point to a set of circles

Tags: integer-programming

My requirement is to find the point closest to three circles. So lets say the three circles are C1, C2, C3. I want to find the point in the space such that the SUM of its distance from C1, C2 and C3 is MINIMUM.

The distance of a given point from a circle is the distance of the given point from the point that lies on the circle and is intersection of the circle with the line joining the given point with the center of the circle.

I am okay to have the solution in Integer domain, which is where I need your help. I understand the problem can be tackled in Real domain by finding partial derivatives on X, Y axes: See the question in this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710547/solving-multivariate-polynomial-to-find-closest-point-to-a-3-or-more-circles

However I realised that solving the multivariate equations is not easy, and also time taking.

I'm not sure if trying to solve it in Integer domain will make the solution simpler and faster. I'm open to thoughts, and even if there are some approximations which will speed up the algo, I would be glad to listen to them.

Comment: I didn't look at this in detail, but would try the following, for the real problem: As in soap bubbles, I suspect it is where the lines to the circle centres meet at 120 degrees (this can be confirmed/refuted by differentiation).  Find the equation of the locus of points at which the centres of two circles subtend 120 degrees.  Then the desired point is the intersection of these three loci.

Comment: Yes, one possible solution is the Fermat point. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point There are a lot of other cases. Sometimes the solution is on one of the circles. Sometimes it is a sort of anti-Fermat point.

Comment: @Carl/Douglas: Most of the times the circles could intersect, which means the Fermat point may not be what I'm looking for. Fermat point would make sense only when the intersection does not happen between circles.

Comment: No, there are times when the Fermat point is optimal even though the circles intersect. There are times when the circles don't intersect, but the Fermat point is not optimal.

Comment: @DouglasZare Then are you saying the radius of the circles do not matter? I am sorry, but from what you are saying, it means only the coordinates of the circles matter, and not the radius. However, we can easily debate that change in radius can easily impact the closest point.

Comment: I never said that. I explicitly said otherwise, that the solution is sometimes on one of the circles. This was left out by the "answers" on math.stackexchange. In addition, the radii of the circles affects which solutions are valid which are not on any circle.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Can you think of simple way to solve this, assuming the case fermat point won't work? An approximation will also do.

Comment: This is minimum steiner tree problem.

Comment: @user3098199: Do you actually prefer taking a long time to get an iterative approximation over using the quadratic formula and Newton's method in 1 dimension?

Comment: With regard to Fermat's point etc, perhaps you can rig up a physical model to estimate where this point would be. See the related MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104714/building-a-physical-model-to-solve-sudoku

Comment: @Benjamin Dickmaan: Why would that be better than using the quadratic formula to find the intersection of circles? People keep suggesting that the quadratic formula is slow, uses calculus, should be avoided, etc. I don't understand.

Comment: I deleted my answer. I regret trying to help people who don't appreciate actual answers.

Comment: I'm sorry to see that Douglas.  Perhaps it is for the best.  After further searching, I am guessing that you answered the wrong question.  Hopefully the right question (and questioner) will come along.  Gerhard "Sometimes Answers The Wrong Question" Paseman, 2014.03.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Douglas's answer will give exact solutions, I would like to suggest two simpler numerical approaches.

**1.** It is clear that the minimum lies in the convex hull of the circles, and that if the sum of distances in the centre of a square of side length $h$ is $S$, its minimum in the square is at least $S-3h/\sqrt{2}$.  Thus an algorithm consisting of choosing an initial point and $h$ covering the convex hull.

At each step:

(a) Divide the square into nine smaller squares by adding eight points around each point in the previous iteration.  So, if the point is at $(x,y)$, the new points will be at $(x\pm h/3,y\pm h/3)$, $(x\pm h/3,y)$ and $(x,y\pm h/3)$.

(b) Divide $h$ by 3

(c) Compute the sum of distances for each new point, $S(x_i,y_i)$ and find the minimum over all points considered so far,

$S_{\rm min}=\min_iS(x_i,y_i)$

(d) Remove points where the sum of distances is more than $\frac{3h}{\sqrt{2}}$ above this minimum, ie any $i$ for which $S(x_i,y_i)>S_{\rm min}+\frac{3h}{\sqrt{2}}$.

This is guaranteed to converge to the correct minimum, and hopefully answers the integer aspect of the OP's question.

**2.** Still easier (but non-rigorous): Use an out-of-the-box multidimensional optimization algorithm, for example in [mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html)  Towards the bottom of that page, four algorithms are described briefly: Nelder-Mead, Differential evolution, Simulated annealing and Random search.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I would like to understand the first approach that you mentioned further. You have me for most of the approach, except for "t each step, divide the square into nine smaller squares by adding eight points around each point in the previous iteration, divide h by 3, compute the sum of distances for each new point, and remove points more than 32√h/2 above the minimum" Can you please elaborate this line further?

Comment: @user3098199 Elaborated as requested...

Comment: Thanks for elaborate edit! Can you provide link for approach 2 which has details of how to solve similar problems? In the link you provided, the details are very minimal, am having a hard time figuring out how its related to this problem

Comment: @user3098199 I added some text - you can easily code the problem in mathematica to use these in-built routines, or use the ideas to develop your own code.  Of course nonlinear optimization is a hard problem, so it is rare that you can be sure of getting the global minimum.

Comment: (I used Mathematica to create the example [below](http://mathoverflow.net/a/160982/6094).)

Comment: Why do you say my answer "eventually" gives exact solutions? It doesn't take long to find the intersection of circles. It's just the quadratic formula. Finding the solutions on the circles can be done algebraically or with Newton's method which converges rapidly. Your approach is the one that takes a significant amount of computational time, not mine.

Comment: I don't understand why an iterative numerical approach is better than an algebraic solution which shows that critical points which were a priori of high degree are actually quadratic and on a short fixed list.

Comment: Please delete the comment disparaging my answer or give an accurate criticism. I don't think you need to misrepresent my answer to give your own.

Comment: @Douglas I answer the question about integer optimization.  As I pointed out in the comment, if the minimum lies on one circle, it is equivalent to Alhazen's problem, famous in antiquity because it is higher degree than quadratic.  To find the exact solution, one needs to enumerate all Fermat and anti-Fermat points plus Alhazen points, and decide which is optimal - certainly feasible and exact as you say, valuable but not as simple.  I will delete the offending word and retain the upvote on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

An example:
$C_1=[(0,0),1]\;,C_2=[(1,0),\frac{4}{5}]\;,C_3=[(2,\frac{3}{2}),\frac{3}{4}]\;.$

Contours show equal distance sums.
$d_{\min}=\frac{3}{4}$ is achieved at $p_{\min} \approx (1.06, 0.80)$.

---

[image: ThreeCirclesFermat]